# Dynamically creating a component inside Modal component - Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, modal-dialog

I am creating my own modal component so far it is going well, I can dynamically create my initial modal component itself but then I am trying to create another component inside the modal component.

With my code below, for the modal container component I have a viewCotainerRef on a template variable which is then creating the component inside that container div. My issue then arrives when I try and render my `DynamicContentComponent` inside the `ModalComponent` I cannot get the viewContainerRef on the first click as it is `undefined`, however on the second click on the modal trigger it is defined.

So I am setting my 'viewContainerRef' on the `DynamicContentComponent` when the `ModalComponent` is generated. Sending it to the render service, when I can clearly see that it console logs out fine. But when I come to render the actual `DynamicContentComponent` using the same `viewContainerRef` it is undefined.

Sorry if this is a bit confusing, code is below but if that is not enough I will post on plunkr after work.

Thanks

ModalComponentService

```
@Injectable()
export class ModalService {
  public showModal: Subject<any> = new Subject();
  public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;
  public injector: Injector;
  private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver;
  private compiler: Compiler;
  private render: RenderService;

  constructor(resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, compiler: Compiler, renderer: RenderService) {
    this.render = renderer;
    this.resolver = resolver;
    this.compiler = compiler;
  }

  public setViewContainerRef(vcRef: ViewContainerRef): void {
    this.viewContainerRef = vcRef;
  }

  public setInjector(injector: Injector): void {
    this.injector = injector;
  }

  public createDialog(module: any, component: any, paramsModal?: Object, paramsComponent?: Object) {

    const componentRef$ = new ReplaySubject();

    this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module).then((data) => {
      const standardModalFactory = data.componentFactories.filter( (singleComponents) => {
        return singleComponents.componentType === StandardModalComponent;
      })[0];

      const modalRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(standardModalFactory);

      modalRef.instance['destroy'] = () => {
        modalRef.destroy();
      };

      Object.assign(modalRef.instance, paramsModal);

      componentRef$.next(modalRef);
      componentRef$.complete();
    });

    this.render.renderComponent(module, component, paramsComponent).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data); 
    });

    return componentRef$;
  }
}
```

ModalComponent

```
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('modalPlaceholder', {read: ViewContainerRef}) container;

  @Output()
  public appModalCloseModal: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<void>();

  public showModal = true;
  private modalService: ModalService;
  public injector: Injector;

  constructor(modalService: ModalService, injector: Injector) {
    this.modalService = modalService;
    this.injector = injector;
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.modalService.setViewContainerRef(this.container);
    this.modalService.setInjector(this.injector);
  }
}
```

ModalComponent Template

```
<div #modalPlaceholder class="appModal-placeholer"></div>
```

StandardModalComponent - which is injected into the container above

```
export class StandardModalComponent extends StandardModal implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('standardModalContent')
  public standardModalContent;

  @Input()
  public appStandardModalHeaderLabel: string;

  private renderService: RenderService;

  constructor(render: RenderService) {
    super();
    this.renderService = render;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.renderService.setModalReference(this.standardModalContent);
  }
}
```

On the Init above this is where it is setting the 2nd viewContainerRef for the content component.

StandardModalComponent - Template

So this is where the component that needs to be displayed in the modal component will be injected in to the reference of `standardModalComponent`

```
<div class="appStandardModal-container">
  <div class="appStandardModal-overlay">
    <div class="appStandardModal-modalDialog">

      <div class="appStandardModal-header">
        <div class="appStandardModal-titleContainer">
          <h3>{{appStandardModalHeaderLabel}}</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="appStandardModal-closeModal">
          <button (click)="closeModal()">
            <fa name="times"></fa>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div #standardModalContent class="appStandardModal-content">

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is my RenderService to dynamically create the desired component inside the `#standardModalContent` reference.

```
@Injectable()
export class RenderService {
  public viewContainer: ViewContainerRef;
  public injectors: Injector;
  private compiler: Compiler;
  public modalComponentReference$: ReplaySubject<any>;

  constructor(compiler: Compiler) {
    this.compiler = compiler;
  }

  public setModalReference(viewContainer: ViewContainerRef): void {
    this.viewContainer = viewContainer;
    console.log('setModalReference', this.viewContainer);
  }

  public setModalInjectorReference(injector: Injector): void {
    this.injectors = injector;
  }

  public renderComponent(module: any, component: any, componentParams?: Object) {
    this.modalComponentReference$ = new ReplaySubject();
    console.log('setModalReference in render component', this.viewContainer);

    const factory = component.componentFactory;
    const createdComponent = this.viewContainer.createComponent(factory);

    Object.assign(createdComponent.instance, componentParams);

    this.modalComponentReference$.next(createdComponent);

    return this.modalComponentReference$;
  }

}
```

When the `service.setModalReference` is initially called on the `standardModalComponent` it is logged out fine, however when I come to call the `renderComponent` method is is undefined on the first click of the modal trigger, however not on any click after.

Probably not useful but gives more of an idea of going on, here is the click trigger on my component below

OpenModalComponent

```
export class OrderedNamesComponent implements IOrderedNames, OnInit {
  @Input()
  public appOrderedNamesName: boolean;

  @Input()
  public appOrderedNamesIndex: number;

  private modalService: ModalService;
  private params: { appStandardModalHeaderLabel: string; onSave: () => void };

  constructor(modalService: ModalService) {
    this.modalService = modalService;
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.setParams();
  }

  public emitToParent() {
    this.modalService.createDialog(AppModule, TestComponentComponent, this.params);
  }

  private setParams(): void {
    this.params = {
      appStandardModalHeaderLabel: 'Select Teams',
      onSave: () => alert('save me')
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `ngAfterViewInit()` lifecycle hook instead of `ngOnInit()` as I think your views are not available at `ngOnInit()`?

Comment: @sugarme yes I have tried the different hook, no effect for me though!

Comment: would be useful if you could create a plunkr or a stackblitz